# Checking if host is online in Cypress

Tags: cypress, ping, web-testing

My tests run on a IOT device which is controlled via a web interface. I want to create a factory reset test which involves a reboot of the device and I want to check in a loop if the device is online ("pingable") again. Is there a way to execute the ping command inside of Cypress and get a return value of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming you mean the standard ping protocol, this is the form. Substitute your device address and reply message.

```js
cy.exec('ping google.com', {failOnNonZeroExit: false})
  .then(reply => {
    expect(reply.code).to.eq(0)
    const expectedMsg = 'Pinging google.com [142.250.66.206] with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 142.250.66.206: bytes=32' 
    expect(reply.stdout).to.satisfy(msg => msg.startsWith(expectedMsg))
  })
```

A loop may not be needed, but if so I'd use a recursive function

```js
function doPing(count = 0) {

  if (count === 10) throw 'Failed to ping';

  cy.exec('ping google.com', {failOnNonZeroExit: false})
    .then(reply => {
      if (reply.code > 0) {

        cy.wait(1000)    // whatever back-off time is required
        doPing(++count)

      } else {
        expect(reply.stdout).to.satisfy(msg => ...)
      }
    })
}

doPing()
```