# How to check a link to a server that does not respond

Tags: javascript, cypress, enotfound-error

Using `cy.request()` with the link URL "http://www.alitots.co.uk/" fails with this error:

> The request failed without a response
>
> We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.
>
> We received this error at the network level:
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [www.alitots.co.uk](http://www.alitots.co.uk)
>
> The request we sent was:
> Method: GET
> URL: http://www.alitots.co.uk/

How do I handle this and carry on checking the other links?

This is the full code:

```js
  cy.get("a:not([href*='mailto:'])").each(($link, index) => {
    const href=$link.prop('href')
    cy.log(href)
    if (href) {
      cy.request({
        url: href, 
        failOnStatusCode:false,
        followRedirect:false,
        failOnNetworkError:false
      })
      .then((response)=>{
        if(response.status >= 400 || response.status == '(failed)') {
          cy.log(` *** link ${index +1} is Broken Link ***`)
          //brokenLinks++
         } else {
          cy.log(` *** link ${index+1} is Active Link ***`) 
         }
       })
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 8):

The error code `ENOTFOUND` means the server is not running.

All you are testing at the moment is the `response`, but there is no server to give a response.

You need to add a ping. If you do it manually in the terminal `ping http://www.alitots.co.uk`:

> Ping request could not find host http://www.alitots.co.uk. Please check the name and try again.

---

This question gives you a way to ping the server from within the test

[**Checking if host is online in Cypress**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509176/checking-if-host-is-online-in-cypress)

`result.stdout` contains the same message as above.

```js
  cy.get("a:not([href*='mailto:'])").each(($link, index) => {
    const href = $link.prop('href')
    if (!href) return

    const url = new URL(href)
    const host = url.hostname
    cy.exec(`ping ${host}`, {failOnNonZeroExit:false}).then(reply => {

      if (result.code !== 0) {
        cy.log(`Could not ping "${href}", result.stdout`)
      } else {

        // now check response
        cy.request({url: href, failOnStatusCode:false, followRedirect:false})
          .then(response => {
            if(response.status >= 400 || response.status == '(failed)') {
              cy.log(` *** link ${index +1} is Broken Link ***`)
              //brokenLinks++
            } else {
              cy.log(` *** link ${index+1} is Active Link ***`) 
            }
          })
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Probably need to change to `response.statusCode >= 400`.

Comment: H, Thankyou for your answer but now all urls(even urls which has response from server )passing through first if block so ping is giving all result.code to 1, any more suggestions  please

Comment: Indeed, it needs to ping the `host` part of the URL only - I added a couple of lines. This works if links are full URL like `http://www.alitots.co.uk`, if you have some partial links you will need more manipulation of the `href` string.