# How to solve Cypress Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND? Unable to run domain validation/existence tests

Tags: javascript, request, cypress

I'm writing an automation which basically reads the list of urls from an excel sheet and check the status of each url whether it's success(200), redirected(301/302) or Not Found(404) and based on the response I'm updating the sheet with the status against each url.

I'm able to cover almost all conditions but struggling with the urls whose domain is either not accessible or non reachable, because it's a network error so whenever my code tries to access those urls the test is getting terminated at that particular stage and the whole automation fails. Instead that I want to skip those urls and update the sheet with the status Non reachable or something like that.

I'm not able to find a correct way to cover this case I tried all my best as a beginner in cypress.

Here I'm adding what I tried.

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

describe('Website Test', () => {
it('should open websites from Excel and update status', () => {
// Read Excel file
cy.readFile('/Link.xlsx', 'binary').then((fileContent) => {
  const workbook = XLSX.read(fileContent, { type: 'binary' });
  const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

  // Get all URLs from the Excel sheet
  const urls = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1, range: 1 });

  // Iterate through each URL
  urls.forEach((url, rowIndex) => {
    const websiteUrl = url[1]; // Assuming the URL is in the first column

    // Check if the websiteUrl is empty, and terminate the test if true
    if (!websiteUrl) {
      cy.log(`Skipping empty row at index ${rowIndex}`);
      return;
    }
    
    // Use cy.request to get the response status, follow redirects
    cy.request({
      url: websiteUrl,
      followRedirect: false,
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    }).then((response) => {
      // Update status in Excel based on the final status
      let status;
      let result;
      if (response.status === 302 || response.status === 301) {
        status = `redirected to ${response.redirectedToUrl}`;
      } else if (response.status === 200) {
        status = 'opened';
      } else {
        status = 'failed';
      }

      XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [[status]], { origin: `C${rowIndex + 2}` });
      XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [[result]], { origin: `D${rowIndex + 2}` });

      // Save the updated Excel file after each request
      const updatedFileContent = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
      cy.writeFile('Link.xlsx', updatedFileContent, 'binary');
    });
  });
});
```

With this approach test is failing at cy.request() for non accessible domains with an error message: **Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bvicameroon.com**

I tried one more approach using **cy.intercept()**.

```
    cy.intercept('GET', websiteUrl, (req) => {
      console.log(req)
      req.continue((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
    }).as('websiteUrlRequest');

    cy.wait('@websiteUrlRequest', { timeout: 10000 }).then((interception) => {
      console.log(interception)
    });
```

With this approach first of all I'm not able to log the req/res of intercept. It is logging interception object inside cy.wait but only for valid domains It's failing on cy.wait() for non accessible domains with error message:

> **CypressError**
> Timed out retrying after 10000ms: cy.wait() timed out
> waiting 10000ms for the 1st request to the route: websiteUrlRequest. No
> request ever occurred

Can anyone suggest me the possible approach to do cover the condition for non accessible domains (Network Error)?

Comment: The tl;dr is that if your endpoint does not return a status code (in the case of `bvicameroon.com`), then `cy.request()` fails and does not look at `failOnStatusCode`.

In this github issues thread there is a workaround using `cy.exec()`, which amounts to using `curl` to run your requests instead of `cy.request()`. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3161

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if host is online in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509176/checking-if-host-is-online-in-cypress)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone having trouble calling `ping` from the `cy.exe()` command, maybe because the OS is incompatable, an alternative is to use the [node-ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) package and call it via a `cy.task()` command.

First install the `ping` package

```js
yarn add ping
```

Then add the task command to `cypress.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const ping = require('ping')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        ping(host) {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            ping.sys.probe(host, (isAlive) => resolve(isAlive))
          })
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

Then in the test, use the `true/false` return value as required

```js
cy.task('ping', 'google.com').then(isAlive => {
  expect(isAlive).to.eq(true)
})

cy.task('ping', 'bvicameroon.com').then(isAlive => {
  expect(isAlive).to.eq(false)
  // or
  if (isAlive) {
    ...
})
```

Comment: It worked as expected. Thanks @Sandra de Las Cruz

Answer (score 5):

The way to check that a URL is reachable is with `ping`.
This answer is relevant to your issue [Checking if host is online in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509176/checking-if-host-is-online-in-cypress).

Broadly, you do that check prior to `cy.request()`, same as empty URL check but it's an asynchronous call so it will check inside the `.then()` callback.

```js
// Check if the websiteUrl is empty
if (!websiteUrl) {
  cy.log(`Skipping empty row at index ${rowIndex}`);
  return;
}

// Check if the websiteUrl is reachable
const host = websiteUrl.replace('https://', '')  // only host part for ping
cy.exec(`ping ${host}`, {failOnNonZeroExit: false}).then(reply => {
  if (reply.code !== 0) {
    cy.log(`Skipping unreachable URL at index ${rowIndex}`);
    return;
  } else {
    cy.request({
      ...
```

If you extract the code to update XL to a function, you can also update after `ping` failure.

```js
function updateXL({status, result}) {
  XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [[status]], { origin: `C${rowIndex + 2}` });
  XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [[result]], { origin: `D${rowIndex + 2}` });

  // Save the updated Excel file after each request
  const updatedFileContent = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
  cy.writeFile('Link.xlsx', updatedFileContent, 'binary');
}

...

// Check if the websiteUrl is reachable
const host = websiteUrl.replace('https://', '')  // only host part for ping
cy.exec(`ping ${host}`, {failOnNonZeroExit: false}).then(reply => {
  if (reply.code !== 0) {
    cy.log(`Skipping unreachable URL at index ${rowIndex}`);
    updateXL({status: 'unknown', result: 'unreachable'})
    return;
  } else {
    cy.request({
      ...
```

---

Simple examples:

```js
cy.exec('ping google.com', {failOnNonZeroExit: false}).then(reply => {
  expect(reply.code).to.eq(0)   // success
  expect(reply.stdout.startsWith('Pinging google.com')).to.eq(true)
})

cy.exec('ping bvicameroon.com', {failOnNonZeroExit: false}).then(reply => {
  expect(reply.code).to.eq(1)   // failed
  expect(reply.stdout.startsWith('Ping request could not find host bvicameroon.com')).to.eq(true)
})
```

[image]

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste an answer from a different question you should mark the question as a duplicate.  This just creates two questions with identical need and response.

Comment: It's a duplicate ***concept***, but the mechanism needs expanding for this particular question. We don't close questions just because they use similar commands.

Comment: Thanks @MeziAtwood for your revert into this. Do we need any settings/package enabled to work with ping? Unfortunately I'm not able to make it work with my setup. I'm trying a very basic command cy.exec('ping google.com') but it's throwing a cypressError timed out after waiting 60000ms

Comment: Not sure what causes that for you. I added two simple examples, one passing one failing.  There is an option `{failOnNonZeroExit: false}` missing from the reference question to allow evaluation of the return code. But that doaesn't affect `ping google.com`. Also note when you get it working, your URL's need to remove the `https://` prefix for testing with `ping` (in case you didn't realize).

Comment: You can also run `ping google.com` from VSCode terminal or separate command prompt to see it working.

Comment: @MeziAtwood I tried the same in my local setup but it's not working for me. I'm not sure but Is there any OS dependancy for this as I'm using it in ubuntu? Yes, I understand that `https://` prefix should not be there. `ping google.com` is working in VS terminal. Here you can find the screenshot attached for my test output https://ibb.co/W2f556K

Comment: Workaroud: It seems like it's not working for accessible domains. When I'm trying to ping bvicameroon.com It is running the test and giving an assertion error that is ok. Please check the attached scrrenshot https://ibb.co/RTzJ6QG